# Why does add(1)(2) work when calling a function?

Tags: python

I've never seen this format before. What is happening when you run

```
add(1)(2)
```

Or

```
add(1)(2)(3)
```

Comment: If `add(1)` returns a function, then adding `(2)` on the end *calls that function* with the parameter 2.  It's exactly the same syntax rule that lets you write `(1)` after `add` to call it.

Comment: This completely depends on the definition of `add`.

Comment: the expected utility for this function is to return the sum when calling add(num1)(num2) etc

Comment: Please post the definition of `add()`.

Comment: This works like *any other expression*. `add(1)(2)` first evaluates starting from the left, `add(1)` is evaluated, it returns *something*, then `<somethign>(2)` is evlauated, i.e., something is called with the argument `2`. If something is callable (e.g. a function or a class) then it might work. If it isn't callable, it will raise a TypeError. Just like `f(x) + y` will first evaluate `f(x)` into *something*, then `<something> + y` will be evaluated, and it will work depending on if `<somethingn>` supports `+`

Comment: I have to create the function, that's what they want. It's a codewars challenge that I do not understand, here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/539a0e4d85e3425cb0000a88/train/python

Comment: That's a terrible question, btw. The only way to solve it is either by using a custom `int` subclass to amke it callable *or* by some serious hijinks to determine if `add(x)(y)` is the last call.... The more *reasonable* way to do this is to make something like an empty call signal the termination, e.g. `add(1)(2)(3)()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*add* would need to be a callable class as follows:

```
class add(int):
    def __call__(self, v):
        return add(self + v)
```

In that way you could assert that (for example):

```
add(1)(4) == 5
```